# Copy custom options from one product to another Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

> Hi i need to copy a custom options from one product to another.

I have search so much on google but

> everywhere it is suggested to create a array than assign ,
>
> but i need to copy them through script.

Please suggest me if someone has some reference for this.

Comment: Can you add more details? At what moment do you want to copy them? Do you want to copy the custom options of some products in the admon, of the items when adding them to the cart?

Comment: i want to copy the options from one product to another through script , not at the time of add to cart.